# @RepositoryRestResource override findAll to only logged in user

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, repository, spring-data-rest

Is there an easier (simpler) way to only return the records for a logged-in user?

- I have person and account entities (one to many from person to account)
- I have `@RepositoryRestResource` (`extends JpaRepository`) for both as well

```java
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name="username")
    private String username;  

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "trader", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

```java
@Entity
public class Account {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn( name = "person_id", nullable = false)
    private Person person;
}
```

```java
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface AccountRepository extends JpaRepository<Account, Long> {}
```

- Is it possible to override the `findAll()` inside the `AccountRepository` to only get accounts for the logged in user?, I haven't been able to get the `@Query` or `@PostAutorize` to work.
- It works by creating an `@BasePathAwareController` and overriding the the `findAll()` from there.  But it seems a bit more coding than needed.

But that the correct way, or is there a better, more efficient way (doing it in the Repository directly)?

Comment: Instead of overriding you could add a new method `findByPersonId` to Account repository and use that in a controller to get list of accounts for the current user